# Pocketing the Queen

Tags: carrom

In Carrom, if both players have one one coin and the queen and one player pocketed their coin before the queen, what is the result?

Comment: Your question is unclear and is mistagged.  Could you please clarify?

Comment: I think I parsed this out a bit

Answer (score 2):

According to the laws of carrom:

> 107. If a player pockets his last C/M by a proper stroke leaving the Queen on the C/B, he shall lose the board by 3 points. If the opponent’s score is 22 or more, he shall lose by 1 point. Also, if a player pockets his last C/M by an improper stroke leaving the Queen on the C/B, he shall lose the board by 3 points. If the opponent’s score is 22 or more, he shall lose by 1 point. If demanded, the opponent shall be awarded one additional point.